# Problems and questions regarding scipy.optimize.minimize in Python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimize

I have some questions and problems regarding scipy's optimize.minimize routine. I would like to minimize the function:

f(eta) = sum_i |eta*x_i - y_i|

with regard to eta. Since I am not familiar with the minimize routine and the corresponding methods, I tried some out. However, using method BFGS raises the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 441, in minimize return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 904, in _minimize_bfgs
A1 = I - sk[:, numpy.newaxis] * yk[numpy.newaxis, :] * rhok
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index
```

which I was not able to solve. Please find code, which causes the error below. I am using Python3 with scipy 0.17.0 and numpy 1.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Furthermore, the method conjugate gradient seems to perform worse than other methods.

Last but not least, I favour estimating the minimum by finding the zero of the first derivative via scipy.optimize.brentq. Is this fine or do you recommend another approach? I prefer robustness over speed.

Here is some code illustrating the problems and questions:

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

def function(x, bs, cs):
    sum = 0.
    for b, c in zip(bs, cs):
        sum += np.abs(x*b - c)
    return sum

def derivativeFunction(x, bs, cs):
    sum = 0.
    for b, c in zip(bs, cs):
        if x*b > c:
            sum += b
        else:
            sum -= b
    return sum

np.random.seed(1000)
bs = np.random.rand(10)
cs = np.random.rand(10)

eta0 = 0.5

res = optimize.minimize(fun=function, x0=eta0, args=(bs, cs), method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
print('Nelder-Mead:\t', res.x[0], function(res.x[0], bs, cs))

res = optimize.minimize(fun=function, x0=eta0, args=(bs, cs,),  method='CG', jac=derivativeFunction, tol=1e-6)
print('CG:\t', res.x[0], function(res.x[0], bs, cs))

x = optimize.brentq(f=derivativeFunction, a=0, b=2., args=(bs, cs), xtol=1e-6, maxiter=100) 
print('Brentq:\t', x, function(x, bs, cs))

#Throwing the error
res = optimize.minimize(fun=function, x0=eta0, args=(bs, cs), method='BFGS', jac=derivativeFunction, tol=1e-6)
print('BFGS:\t', res.x[0], function(res.x[0], bs, cs))
```

Its output is:

```
Nelder-Mead:     0.493537902832 3.71986334101
CG:  0.460178525461 3.72659733011
Brentq:  0.49353725172947666 3.71986347245
```

where the first value is the position of the minimum and the second value the minimum itself. The output misses the error message from above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might consider breaking this down into a few, more concise questions with [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People may me more inclined to help that way. "*Furthermore*" and "*last but not least*" belong in a speech, not a SE or SO question. Take a look around at other questions that are attracting answers.

Comment: In this case, can you remove parts of the script until you have the smallest example that still causes the problem? Then maybe print out the arguments to the call and see if they are actually what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

In SciPy 1.12, your code produces the output:

```
Nelder-Mead:     0.49353790283203125 3.7198633410125184
CG:  0.5 3.729437707615416
Brentq:  0.4935375286374616 3.7198634165481654
BFGS:    0.4756548864945291 3.7234732416312872
```

with no warnings or errors.

> Last but not least, I favour estimating the minimum by finding the zero of the first derivative via `scipy.optimize.brentq`. Is this fine or do you recommend another approach? I prefer robustness over speed.

This is a very good solution. If the derivative crosses zero exactly once within the bracket you provide, `brentq` is essentially guaranteed to find the zero-crossing. That is very robust, and it is *also* 10x faster the fastest of the other methods you suggested.

This is not surprising because `brentq` is specifically for functions of one variable. It takes advantage of the simplicity of the scalar case, whereas the others are for functions with any number of inputs.

(For sufficiently smooth functions, finding the zero-crossing of the derivative can typically be done to greater precision than finding the minimum of a function. This is because the slope of the function is zero at the minimum, so the minimizer of a function in 64-bit precision may not be unique, but the zero-crossing typically is.)

Another reasonable solution would be to use the scalar minimizer [`scipy.optimize.brent`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brent.html).

```py
optimize.brent(function, brack=(eta0-0.1, eta0+0.1), args=(bs, cs))
# 0.49353790029693073
```

If you provide a valid [three-point bracket](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bracket.html) and the function is unimodal within the bracket, it is also essentially guaranteed to find the minimizer. But it seems to be a little slower in this case, and finding a valid three-point minimization bracket is usually a little more work than finding a valid two-point rootfinding bracket, so go ahead and stick with `brentq`.